# .Net Core 2.1 Azure Reply URL

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Just published a test web application from VS2019 (.Net Core 2.x) to Azure.  I am getting an error about setting the Reply URL.  I have done this in my app service on Azure, but where to set it in the web code.

The nearest documentation I can find references a web.config but I only have a appsettings.json file.   I assume there should be other Azure properties I can set as well (in appsettings), but cant find any documentation (that is up-to-date and relevant).

Anyone know how to set the Reply URL correctly?

Comment: please share what you did and what is the error you get

Comment: @TwoSeven Would you kindly try this out. and let me know if you have any more query. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In vs2019 I just created a default web app using core, in Azure I just created a basic app service/app registration and set the reply_url there.   I am now trying to figure out how to change the basic web app in VS to update the reply url - but the documentation is not up to scratch. So I am hoping someone can tell me how to do it.

Comment: @TwoSeven Please have a look now. I have updated the answer for you. If you have still any problem just let me know. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @TwoSeven Please try my new answer which is more details and the complete enhancement of previous answer. Let me know if you have any more complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your more clarification make sure you have followed the steps as exactly...

**Step: 1**

Take a new dotnet core web application and configure like below[image]

**Step: 2**

Copy your tenant domain name from azure portal.

[image]

**step: 3**

paste it in domain specifier on like below

[image]

**Step: 4**

Configure you subscription and resource information
[image]

**Step: 5**

Copy the the publish URL once the application published like below

[image]

**step: 6**

Find the published application on azure portal like below:

[image]

**Step: 7**

Click on your application go to `settings` and then click on `Reply URLs`

Just paste your published application URL on Reply URLs portion like this `https://twosevenreplyurlcase20190425072649.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc` and click on save.
See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Step: 8**

In first browsing you would get that reply URL error like below:

[image]

After successful configuration just refresh your azure portal and browser your published URL for example :
`https://twosevenreplyurlcase20190425072649.azurewebsites.net/`

See the screen shot:

[image]

If you have any more problem just feel free to share. Thank you.

Comment: This was the steps that I was following.   I have it working now - the issue was that VS2019 was publishing everything as http not https.  I noticed the difference when looking at the web deploy publish profile and saw that the server was https (which would be expected).   I will mark your post as the answer as it led to me finding the solution and I appreciate the effort put in to helping me solve it.

Comment: Yeah its also true azure portal except https. Tough in next step I would have asked for your sample to compare with but glad to hear that its working now . One more thing never give up as I never did that. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

When you would publish your dotnet core application on to portal it will generate a a unique application url for you. Let's say, below URL for example

> https://testreplyurldotnetcode20190424042839.azurewebsites.net/

when you browse your url you would encountered an error like below.

[image]

To avoid this error you have to configure it on azure portal like below.

```
https://testreplyurldotnetcode20190424042839.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc
```

> **Note:** Just put a extra back slash `/` and set `signin-oidc` after the
>   slash

See the below screen shot:

[image]

After configuration just browse your web url you would encountered any more error . Thank you very much and happy coding!

Comment: @TwoSeven have you tired this out?

Comment: No-one has been able to answer my original question on where is the accurate documentation.  Since my launchconditions and appsettings files are different from what people are telling me, I suspect it doesnt exist.

Comment: @TwoSeven You can also try as exactly how I have created the dotnet core app with changing the authentication with azure ad. and once you have publish it, latter configure the portal. Let me know if you have any more issue. Thank you.